# AWS Java SDK: AbortedException on call to AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

We are trying to read from an Amazon SQS Queue from a Java program running on an EC2 instance. On occasion, we get a `com.amazonaws.AbortedException`. Our code looks like this:

```
AmazonSQSClient sqs = new AmazonSQSClient(myCredentials);
ReceiveMessageRequest request = new ReceiveMessageRequest()
            .withWaitTimeSeconds(20)
            .withMaxNumberOfMessages(1)
            .withQueueUrl(queueUrl);
ReceiveMessageResult result = sqs.receiveMessage(request);
```

And our stack trace looks like this:

```
com.amazonaws.AbortedException: 
at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.abortIfNeeded(SdkFilterInputStream.java:51)
at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:65)
at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:159)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(XMLEntityManager.java:2890)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:674)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1304)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDocumentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1255)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:253)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.setInputSource(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:199)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.<init>(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:184)
at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.getXMLStreamReaderImpl(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:277)
at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.createXMLStreamReader(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:129)
at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.createXMLEventReader(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:78)
at com.amazonaws.http.StaxResponseHandler.handle(StaxResponseHandler.java:91)
at com.amazonaws.http.StaxResponseHandler.handle(StaxResponseHandler.java:43)
at com.amazonaws.http.response.AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.handle(AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.java:70)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1501)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1222)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1035)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:747)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:721)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:672)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:654)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:518)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:1663)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:1639)
at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1269)
at <our code>
```

The documentation for `com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient` does not tell us to expect an AbortedException.

We are using SDK version 1.11.77.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though the javadoc on [`AbortedException`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/AbortedException.html) is sparse, it is a subclass of `AmazonClientException` & `RuntimeException` (which do not have to be declared).  Also, the [AWS Exception handling docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-exceptions.html) says this:

> AmazonClientException indicates that a problem occurred inside the Java client code, either while trying to send a request to AWS or while trying to parse a response from AWS. An AmazonClientException is generally more severe than an AmazonServiceException, and indicates a major problem that is preventing the client from making service calls to AWS services. For example, the AWS SDK for Java throws an AmazonClientException if no network connection is available when you try to call an operation on one of the clients.

`AbortedException` is generally thrown when the SDK  handles an `InterruptedException` (ie: [the thread was signalled to stop doing work](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)). For your purposes though, you probably just want to retry the operation.

(If you're the one doing the explicit `Thread.interrupt` to cause this though, then it's up to you on how you want to proceed - either treat it as a signal to stop work, or just retry the operation)

Comment: We perform the S3 bucket upload inside the "finally" block, Although we have called the Thread.currentThread,interrupt inside implementation block.
Why is it throwing "AbortException" when it is in "finally" block which should not affect the exception which currently throwing.

Comment: @Mudithasumanathunga - it would be best to ask your question as an actual standalone question (which may refer to this as well as your own code), rather than ask it in a comment here.